# How to pass several parameters from view to controller's method

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Can you tell me how to pass several parameters from the view to the controller's function in the most convenient way?

JSP-view:

```
<h2>${topic.getName()}</h2>
<h3>${topic.getText()}</h2>

<form:form method="post" commandName="newComment">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <td><form:label path="text">Input comment</form:label></td>
        </div>

        <div class="textarea">
            <form:textarea path="text" />
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Comment" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form:form>
```

As you can see, we have **topic** and **newComent** properties, which represent topic and comment entities.
  Here is a controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addComment/{topicId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveComment(@ModelAttribute("newComment")Comment comment, BindingResult result, Model model){

    validate(comment, result);
    if (result.hasErrors() )
        {
            return "//";
        }
        return "redirect:details/";
    }
}
```

the **comment** entity is recognized fine but i need an instance of Topic object (or it's ID) as well. An instance of topic object was accessible in the view, and topic ID is a part of a response. Can you give me an idea how can I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you get the topic model if you have the `topicId`? It's in your path.
You can get it by adding `@PathVariable` annotation in your method parameters.

```
public String saveComment(@PathVariable String topicId, @ModelAttribute("newComment")Comment comment, BindingResult result, Model model){
```